# Voice over or accessibility for UIPage control

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

Current implementation of my iOS app is like I have a pagination enabled `UIScrollView`. I have to enable voice over for the same which should voice over the use for pages like `"this is the first view", "this is the custom view","this is the nature Photos view"` on scrolling to the 1st,2nd or 3rd pages.

Problem- problem is the voice over repeats like Page 1 of 3, page 2 of 3, Page 3 of 3 rather than the given messages.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Accessibility Attributes like Label in this case and set the message you want.

You can follow [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/142058/ios-accessibility-tutorial) wonderful tutorial, which will also guide you to debug and test.